# How to pass input to condition (e.g. "If") while iterating a workflow sequence in Rehosted designer

Tags: workflow-foundation

My sequence can have custom activities and conditions.
Some activities are condition based i.e. will execute if the condition is satisfied with the given input from previous activity.
I need an way to pass an input to the the condition.

Design is like below:

Each custom activity will be triggered by execute and actual completion will come through a different thread. That means i will be waiting till that activity is completed/success before i trigger the next activity in the sequence.

That's why i had to iterate the sequence instead of direct call to "WorkflowInvoker.Invoke" by passing the entire sequence.

I am iterating like below:

[image]

I tried passing arguments/variables which are actually not accessible at activity level. I mean user can define an argument(e.g. "dummyinput"), use the argument in the "If" condition (e.g. dummyinput = "pass"); and his intention is  to verify this value with the passed input through code (response from previous activity) while executing "If".

Is there any way i can pass the input to "If" condition and get it passed/fail and proceed to next activity based of return from "If"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i will try to answer my question or describe the way i have changed my design to fullfil my requirement:

My actual requirement was:
Each custom activity will be triggered by execute and actual completion will come through a different thread. That means i will be waiting till that activity is completed/success before i trigger the next activity in the sequence.

To achieve this, my initial implementation was done by iterating the activities in the workflow and executing an activity only after examining the result argument received from the previous activity.
And hence i was looking for techinique to pass inputs programmatically to "If" condition received from previous command.
[similar to the above code snippets]

But eventually i failed to achieve this.

Then i got to know about "Asynchronous Activities in WF". 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/creating-asynchronous-activities-in-wf]

With this, i could remove the iteration while calling "WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(...)" to receive the output from the activity, and hence the need of passing this as input to "If" condition.
Instead i could wait in the executing activity itself for the other thread to update the completion status back to the activity and then complete by calling "EndExecute". And because i have choosen to define my activities deriving from "AsyncCodeActivity", i could easily attach the output to inbuilt "Result" out argument and user can now use a variable (of mytype) to store the "Result" (in rehosted designer) and use the same in "If" condition (this is handled by WF framework itself).

[image]